# Where are relationship field data stored?

Tags: database, fields

In the EE database, I see that `exp_channel_fields`.`field_id` = 4 refers to a relationship in my `Channel-A` (channel_id = 1). I assume that channel data for that field should be stored in my `exp_channel_data`.`field_id_4`. Is this right? I do not see any data in that column, despite me going into Channel-A and making sure that I have selected a value from the relationship field.

I'm trying to build a query that gets a distinct list of url titles from the relationship field if that title was selected in Channel A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relationships are stored in `exp_relationships` - the `exp_channel_data` content for a relationship field is irrelevant.

So your query would need to do a join between `exp_channel_titles` and `exp_relationships`.